# How to properly configure docker-compose.yml file created by Visual Studio (IDE)

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose

I am running C# in latest version of VS 2019 (Pro) on latest Windows 10 (Pro)

I converted my project (using MS Assistant) from Net Framework to Net 5.0.

All works well -> until I containerize.

Pre-containerization: My process architecture:

```
Logger TseLogger
Search engine shard 1 of 2 (TseShard -shardId 0)
Search engine shard 2 of 2 (TseShard -shardId 1)
```

Note that the 'shard' code is the identical code. **The distinction is the 'shardId' run-time parameter**.

In my solution I want to start **1 logger** and **2 shards**.

I could not figure out how to tell VS to start 2 copies of the same project (each with its own runtime parameters) so (as a kludge so I could test it) I cloned the TseShard project into 'TseShard 2' project and added it to the list of projects to start.

I could now set breakpoints anywhere in the code and debug (single-step as needed).

I am happy as a *pig-in-you-know-what*.

Next step was to containerize the projects.

So I want to generate 2 images
**Logger** (TseLogger)
**Search engine shard** (TseShard)

And, from the images, generate 3 containers: **1 logger** and **2 shards**.

I added **Orchestration** (docker-compose) support to my solution and Docker support to my TseLogger and TseShard projects.

I edited the auto-generate (by VS 2019) docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  tselogger:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}tselogger-2-3-0-6
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: TseLogger/Dockerfile

  tseshard0:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}tseshard0-2-3-0-6
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: TseShard/Dockerfile
    ports: [52949]
    volumes: 
        - d:/MyData:/MyData
    command: -shardId 0 

  tseshard1:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}tseshard1-2-3-0-6
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: TseShard/Dockerfile
    ports: [52950]
    volumes: 
        - d:/MyData:/MyData
    command: -shardId 1
```

Note that I added the suffix '-2-3-0-6' (code assembly version) to the images.

Note also that I named the shard services as '**tseshard0**' and '**tseshard1**'

My expectation is that it allows me to keep images of different code versions so Production can run a stable release while Dev will run new (test) releases.

My expectation is that I can reuse the same docker image (based on docker build of TseShard/Dockerfile) for both shards.

Anyway, it builds (seemingly correct).

For all its worth, the auto-generated (by VS) TseShard/Docker file (I did not edit this one):

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TseShard/TseShard.csproj", "TseShard/"]
COPY ["Utils/Utils.csproj", "Utils/"]
COPY ["BinarySerialization/BinarySerialization.csproj", "BinarySerialization/"]
COPY ["Interfaces/Interfaces.csproj", "Interfaces/"]
COPY ["JsonCompare/JsonCompare.csproj", "JsonCompare/"]
COPY ["Networking/Networking.csproj", "Networking/"]
COPY ["FilterScoring/FilterScoring.csproj", "FilterScoring/"]
COPY ["DataAccess/DataAccess.csproj", "DataAccess/"]
COPY ["TseClient/TseClient.csproj", "TseClient/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TseShard/TseShard.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TseShard"
RUN dotnet build "TseShard.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TseShard.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TseShard.dll"]
```

I set breakpoints at 'Main' for the logger and the shard code C# modules.

Finally, I start the docker-compose project.

It builds properly (so it seems).

Issue #1: I get an error message box from VS saying: Can not find the container with the name starting with 'TseShard'  (see image below)

[image]

Issue #2: I'm not sure why it is looking for a container named 'TseShard' (which is the project name, not the image name, and not the service name).

Issue #3: The Output window from Container Tools shows:

```
========== Debugging ==========
docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "label=com.docker.compose.service" --filter "name=^/TseShard$" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
========== Debugging ==========
docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "label=com.docker.compose.service" --filter "name=^/TseShard$" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
```

Clearly the 'docker ps' is filtering on "name=^/TseShard$" which is looking for exactly 'TseShard'.

But I only defined services for TseShard0 and TseShard1.

See attached images.

Docker shows that the Logger is still running, and the two shards exited.

[image]

For sure, I did not reach a breakpoint (at the literal start of 'Main').

I would appreciate any help in setting up the debugging correctly so that I could set break points.

I am ultimately planning to get this to work on Linux 2 on AWS.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Having this exact same issue

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Have anyone managed to resolve this problem at any point?

Answer (score 0):

RE: Can not find the container with the name starting with 'container.name'

I've had this issue often and only just now found one way to fix it in visual studio with a docker-compose project:

I went into the docker project context menu, Debug, Start new instance.  It worked.  I tried running from F5 after that and it works.

I think there may be many niche conditions that cause this error so this fix may or may not work for you.

I never found the root cause.